# Why double curly braces in Angular/JS are called interpolation?

Tags: angularjs, angular, syntax, semantics, string-interpolation

After more than a year of working with Angular/JS, I still don't have an intuitive understanding of what is **interpolation** (*e.g.* `{{1+4}}` ). What is the origin of the of the term (in Angular/JS context) and does it have anything in common with the mathematical term?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Interpolation - the insertion of something of a different nature into something else"*.

It's a term used for embedding expressions into template literal, which work as placeholders.

In JavaScript you can have the same concept with string interpolation:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 4;
console.log(`Interpolated result is: ${a+b}`); // note: the quotes ``
```

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled by the same thing, having only recently begun learning Angular. In my training from college, "interpolation" was a strictly mathematical term. This definition makes slightly more sense for me: "Another way of describing it is the act of inserting or interjecting an intermediate value between two other values."